# Build war file: java.sql.SQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: java, spring, ubuntu, tomcat, mariadb

I got an error while trying to build war file on Tomcat server in Ubuntu server

```
2021-11-05 08:00:35,705 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] k.c.e.b.ByolServerApplication [SpringApplication.java:637] No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-11-05 08:00:39,578 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] o.a.t.j.p.ConnectionPool [DirectJDKLog.java:182] Unable to create initial connections of pool.
java.sql.SQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.get(ExceptionMapper.java:173)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.getException(ExceptionMapper.java:110)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1113)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.Utils.retrieveProxy(Utils.java:503)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection.newConnection(MariaDbConnection.java:155)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:86)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:310)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:203)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:735)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:667)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:482)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:154)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:131)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:326)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:366)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup.getDatabase(DatabaseLookup.java:72)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties.determineDatabase(JpaProperties.java:139)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.jpaVendorAdapter(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:105)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7a17a50c.CGLIB$jpaVendorAdapter$6(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7a17a50c$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$b60d6f15.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7a17a50c.jpaVendorAdapter(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:86)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5225)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:980)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1852)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.authentication(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:856)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.handleConnectionPhases(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:777)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connect(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:451)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1109)
    ... 89 common frames omitted
```

Here my config:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://60.152.228.28:3306/students
spring.datasource.username=tawxin
spring.datasource.password=E1290090
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

And my DB info:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| students         |
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
+--------------------+


MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT user,authentication_string,plugin,host FROM mysql.user;
+------------+-----------------------+-------------+-----------+
| user       | authentication_string | plugin      | host      |
+------------+-----------------------+-------------+-----------+
| root       |                       | unix_socket | localhost |
| tawxin     |                       |             | localhost |
+------------+-----------------------+-------------+-----------+
```

I don't understand I only use the account '**tawxin**' but when I build it gives an error in accout '**root**'

I've tried looking for the keyword **'root'** in the entire source code but it's nowhere to be found.

Could you guys give me a solution to fix it.
Thanks

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: I think it might actually not be configuring the datasource from the properties, but rather using defaults which is (root).  Can you confirm if your properties are actually loaded up in the code?

Comment: Yup, the infomation in config file were built.
But it only get "root" account

Comment: Please show your are configuring your datasource @NguyenPhong  and your Spring config class, and the full stacktrace

Comment: Hi guys, I have just update full stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

I guess `60.152.228.28` is a remote server. This is a [privileges](https://docs.rackspace.com/support/how-to/mysql-connect-to-your-database-remotely/) issue.
Execute this command to grant privileges to your `root`:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '%password%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

And then grant privileges to your user `tawxin`

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'tawxin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '%password%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

But in the real world, it is not a good practice to grant all the privileges to a user other than `root`. You can manage all those privileges in your client.

Comment: but in the source code i just point to the user account as "tawxin" not "root"

Comment: Have you grant the privileges?

Comment: Yes, I have. But I only grant for "tawxin"